# Grails fails to resolve dependency

Tags: java, grails

I cannot figure out why grails fails to resolve dependency.

When I ran

```
grails war --stacktrace --verbose
```

I could see in the log:

```
...

Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/8.0.33/tomcat-8.0.33.pom

...
```

but the link could be opened and downloaded in the browser. I thought that proxy might cause it. But after I set it with:

```
grails add-proxy client --host=<ip> --port=<port>
```

the error remained.

I'm using

Grails 2.5.6

Java 1.8

Windows 10

I cannot figure out how dependency resolution mechanism works in Grails.
I also tried to run Grails 3.3.9 right after the extraction of the downloaded zip-archive. I ran grails not from a Grails-project folder.

And the first I saw was:

```
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: Could not find artifact org.grails:grails-bom:pom:3.3.9 in nexus (http://<ip>:<port>/nexus/content/groups/public) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

How does it know about

```
http://<ip>:<port>/nexus/content/groups/public
```

This is a setting from my Maven. How are they related?

Answer (score 0):

After you run `grails add-proxy client ...` you need to tell Grails to use that proxy with `grails set-proxy client`.

If you want to review it, the proxy config is stored in %USERPROFILE%\.grails\ProxySettings.groovy

`add-proxy` should add the proxy definition and `set-proxy` should set an unique line `currentProxy='client'`

Grails 3 uses Gradle as the build system so I guess you configured Gradle to use a Maven repo in %USERPROFILE%\.gradle\settings.gradle

Comment: I did nothing. I just extracted the archive with grails 3.3.9 and run the command in a folder that didn't contain any grails app.

Comment: The config for grails 2 proxy and gradle is not saved in the scope of a folder or application, but global for your user in your users home folder.

Comment: When I wrote my comment I meant your words "I guess you configured Gradle to use a Maven". I couldn't configure it as I ran grails right after extraction. I also don't have .gradle folder

Comment: I understand, sorry. I had my focus on your point that grails picked a config from your maven. I was not sure if you mean maven project config or perhaps maven repository config for gradle. That settings could be made long before you extracted the grails zip by e.g. your IDE. Did at least set-proxy helped?